# Why does my data values change after cutting?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am generating data and I wanted it to be in a specific length so I ave to cut it. My generated data is done through the code shown below.

So my original data is called "My_Data" and from there I am choosing randmon set of columns and concat them together.

```
df = []

a = My_Data[random.sample(dff.columns.levels[0].tolist(),1)]

for i in range(35):
  a = pd.concat([dff[random.sample(a.columns.levels[0].tolist(),1)], a.set_index(a.index+random.randrange(4000, 10000, 10))], axis=1)
  a[np.isnan(a)] = 0

  b = a.droplevel(0, axis=1)
  random_data = b.sum(level=0,axis=1)

  df.append(random_data)
data = pd.concat(df)
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
data1
```

Output []:

```
    node1   node2   node3   node4   node5   node6   node7   node8   node9
0   3.035000e-03    -5.021360e-04   -1.620000e-03   2.665000e-04    -1.291200e-03   6.070000e-04    -1.770720e-03   -6.259200e-04   2.499230e-03
1   4.774790e-03    -8.560150e-04   -2.296870e-03   3.504000e-04    -1.766300e-03   8.181000e-04    -2.497020e-03   -9.983000e-04   3.803120e-03
2   4.751550e-03    -9.729233e-04   -1.737980e-03   2.336000e-04    -1.198800e-03   5.454000e-04    -1.867610e-03   -1.003620e-03   3.504390e-03
3   3.284900e-03    -8.116050e-04   -2.928940e-04   6.173000e-05    6.160000e-05    3.130000e-06    -2.838200e-04   -6.552750e-04   1.956140e-03
4   4.605290e-03    -1.194053e-03   -6.555800e-04   3.613000e-04    -4.974300e-04   2.247000e-04    -6.639700e-04   -9.705500e-04   2.835680e-03
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
4741305 5.101000e-12    3.366000e-12    3.321000e-12    -2.330500e-11   -4.199700e-11   -2.296800e-11   -7.675000e-13   -6.851000e-12   -2.594000e-12
4741306 5.731500e-12    4.072000e-12    3.961000e-12    -2.278100e-11   -4.076900e-11   -2.250300e-11   1.341000e-13    -5.682000e-12   -1.680000e-12
4741307 6.254500e-12    4.817000e-12    4.545000e-12    -2.238100e-11   -3.958600e-11   -2.194600e-11   9.445000e-13    -4.434000e-12   -8.070000e-13
4741308 6.810100e-12    5.619000e-12    5.099900e-12    -2.183300e-11   -3.830300e-11   -2.142100e-11   1.804400e-12    -3.094000e-12   5.520000e-14
4741309 7.377500e-12    6.508000e-12    5.660100e-12    -2.129600e-11   -3.698000e-11   -2.084200e-11   2.691122e-12    -1.656000e-12   9.355000e-13
4741310 rows × 9 columns
```

So I generated few more of these data to create one data with length of 19800000.
But as I generated more data, the length exceeds 19800000, so I have to cut it. And I cut it using the code below.

```
w_tendon = pd.concat([data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6])
w_tendon.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
w_tendon = w_tendon[:19800000]
w_tendon
```

Output []:

```
    node1   node2   node3   node4   node5   node6   node7   node8   node9
0   0.001634    -0.000270   -0.000872   0.000144    -0.000695   0.000327    -0.000953   -0.000337   0.001346
1   0.002571    -0.000461   -0.001236   0.000189    -0.000951   0.000440    -0.001345   -0.000538   0.002048
2   0.002558    -0.000524   -0.000936   0.000126    -0.000646   0.000294    -0.001006   -0.000540   0.001887
3   0.001769    -0.000437   -0.000158   0.000033    0.000033    0.000002    -0.000153   -0.000353   0.001053
4   0.000682    -0.000211   0.000677    0.000032    0.000699    -0.000227   0.000743    -0.000043   0.000021
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
19799995    0.000012    -0.008392   -0.003548   -0.002022   -0.002801   -0.001892   -0.003890   -0.008508   0.000218
19799996    -0.000387   -0.008805   -0.003538   -0.002226   -0.003316   -0.002100   -0.003807   -0.008928   -0.000255
19799997    -0.001015   -0.008864   -0.003686   -0.002409   -0.003708   -0.002283   -0.003876   -0.008991   -0.000951
19799998    -0.001838   -0.008582   -0.003978   -0.002609   -0.003932   -0.002480   -0.004083   -0.008706   -0.001840
19799999    -0.002786   -0.008040   -0.004364   -0.002838   -0.003993   -0.002702   -0.004376   -0.008152   -0.002858
19800000 rows × 9 columns
```

As you can see the values change from scientific notification to a completely different set of values.

Anyone can help me do a fix? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please attempt plain text format and then pasting

Comment: can you please, enlighten me more how to do it? Thank you very much

Comment: On Windows, you can use the combination Ctrl + Shift + V to paste without formatting in several major programs, such as Google Chrome. If the app you need to paste into doesn't support this, check out the below options for other ways.

If you're a Mac user, you're all set. macOS includes the shortcut Option + Command + Shift + V to paste without formatting anywhere in the OS.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost. You mean I copy and paste everything?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missed `.iloc` notation and may be `axis=0`. You could try to change it as follows:

```
w_tendon = pd.concat([data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6], axis=0)
...
w_tendon = w_tendon.iloc[:19800000, :]
```

Comment: I still got the same problem :(

Comment: If the number of columns are the same for the data frames (data1, ... data6), you need to specify `axis=0` option to `pd.concat()` function.

Comment: Yeah, still the same :(

Comment: @KimYejun Well, you could remove w_tendon.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True). In addition, have you used the same code for generating data1 to data6?

Comment: @abyssolver I need that part of the code. And Yes, I used similar codes to generate data1 to data6. I actually figured out my problem, it was just a formatting issue. Thank you anyway :)